# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ext' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, string, variables, python-2.7, local

I'm new to programming and Python--perfect storm...

Despite being long, this is only a snippet of over 1300 lines of original code.  What I'm adding is the ability to

- split filenames into root.ext
- identify the file extension (ext)
- limit file upload to specific file extensions (extList)
- Throw/display exception if file extension is not in extList
- allow file upload if file is in the extList
- rename the file using the original file extension

The code worked until I added the file extension logic.  Traceback from apache log is the last couple of lines but I can't solve the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ext' referenced before assignment` exception.

Line 1024, `ext not in extList` which causes the code to stop is just above the traceback lines.

Help?  What am I missing here?

```
def HandleProcessFormRequest(uploadWhat,
                             uploadPath,
                             formInfoHtml,
                             fieldStorage):
    WritePrologueHtml(uploadWhat = uploadWhat)

    uploadFileitem = fieldStorage["upload_file"]
    if ((uploadFileitem == None)        or
        (not uploadFileitem.filename)   or
        (uploadFileitem.filename == "") or
        (not uploadFileitem.file)):
        WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
            html = "You must specify the upload file.",
            uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
            formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
            fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
        return

    storeFilename = ""
    if uploadWhat == "c130j":
        tailNumber = GetValidFormSelectValue(
            name         = "tail-number",
            options      = C130JTailNumberOptions,
            fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
        if tailNumber == "":
            WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
                html         = "You must specify a valid tail number.",
                uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
                formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
                fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
            return
        base = GetValidFormSelectValue(
            name         = "base",
            options      = C130JBaseOptions,
            fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
        if base == "":
            WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
                html         = "You must specify a valid base.",
                uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
                formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
                fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
            return
        downloadDate = GetValidFormDateValue(
            name         = "download-date",
            fieldStorage = fieldStorage,
            defaultValue = None)
        if (downloadDate is None) or (downloadDate == ""):
            WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
                html         = "You must specify a valid download date.",
                uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
                formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
                fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
            return

        extList = [".fdr", ".fdt", ".dat"]

        if ext not in extList:
            WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
                html         = "You may only upload fdr / fdt / dat files",
                uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
                formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
                fieldStorage = fieldStorage)

        root, ext = os.path.splitext(splitfilename)

        if ext in extList:
            ext = str(ext.lower())    
            return ext
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vhosts/isis-pmr/profile/upload/c130jupload.py", line 7, in <module>
    formInfoHtml = None)
  File "/home/vhosts/isis-pmr/profile/upload/uploadlib.py", line 1371, in HandleRequest
    fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
  File "/home/vhosts/isis-pmr/profile/upload/uploadlib.py", line 1024, in HandleProcessFormRequest
    if ext not in extList:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ext' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Your function `def ext(string): return ext` doesn't make sense, but may provide a clue to the problem you are experiencing (note, though, that it is unrelated to your actual error message). What do you expect that function to do?

Comment: I cut out all the code that wasn't the issue here, making your post a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `ext` is not defined at that line, so the error is not surprising. You don't actually define it until the *next* statement:

```
if ext not in extList:
    WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
        html         = "You may only upload fdr / fdt / dat files",
        uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
        formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
        fieldStorage = fieldStorage)

root, ext = os.path.splitext(splitfilename)
```

You need to move that last line to *before* the line where you use `ext`. You can combine the test with the *other* `if ext in extList:` test below it:

```
root, ext = os.path.splitext(splitfilename)

ext = ext.lower()
if ext in extList:
    return ext
else:
    WriteErrorAndFormAndEpilogueHtml(
        html         = "You may only upload fdr / fdt / dat files",
        uploadWhat   = uploadWhat,
        formInfoHtml = formInfoHtml,
        fieldStorage = fieldStorage)
```

Note that I altered how `ext` is lower-cased here; there is no point in testing `ext` against a list of lower-case extensions otherwise; `ext` without lowercasing will not be in `extList` unless it *already* is lowercase.

Comment: ... operator error...I edited my original post above.  I changed the code the way you suggested, only to create a new problem. Now I have an unexpected indent error for a "try" statement.  I added the lines above an added #comments to the right of the code.  Thanks!

Comment: @iassllc: That's because your indentation is all over the place. Indentation in Python is very important, and your `try:` needs to match the previous line. Since this is a **new** problem, you should keep this out of this question, really. Keep the post useful for future visitors too, not just yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what the UnboundLocal is saying is that you referenced a variable before you assigned it a value.

```
 >> if ext not in extList:
 ....
 >> root, ext = os.path.splitext(splitfilename)
```

May be, try to put the root, ext assignment before you ever ask to use ext?